# How to set font size to a rich text box field in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

I am using vb 6 and crystal report 8.5. I have a field called **Instruction** whose data type nvarchar. Previously i was saving plain text data in Instruction field. But now i am saving **txtRTF** data in Instruction field to save instruction in local language.
 So now **my database contains some records with instructions as plain text** and some records of instruction like {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\

When i try to print this data in crystal report. **Font size for plain text is different and instruction  with rtf data with differnt font size**. I want to same size for all records of instruction field.
Even I tried to use formula for Font size but it did not work.

```
If Len(Medical.Instructions}) > 1 then 9
```

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Post the formula and screenshot of the varied font size for further investigation of this issue.

Comment: Thank you. After right click on 'instruction' Field in crystal report -> Edit field - > Under font tab, for Size , I have written formula as  
 If Len(Medical.Instructions}) > 1 then 9

Comment: Can you try with else condition as well. Like add else 1 (Just to check what goes into if condition is not met, does the formula works at all or not?)

Comment: Thanks July Ordinary. I have changed as ,   If Len(Medical.Instructions}) > 1 then 9 else 12       still its not working. I think this is bcoz of rich text field. I have set that Instructions to RTF text like In format editor ->Paragraph Formatting -> Text Interpretation = RTF Text. I think thats why its not showing font size properly.

Comment: Please refer to this link, yes RTF is the culprit. Check how can you play around it. https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1214798

Comment: July Ordinary thank you. I got the solution. While saving rich text box data (i.e. Instructions text box data) into database i have given combo boxes for selecting font name and font size for it. And by default i have set font name and size to the values that i require. And then finally storing into database. So when i print report in crystal report it is showing font name and size which i wanted.